How to reactively process kafka messages using Micronaut-Kafka
So I have a simple Kafka consumer using Micronaut that works:
@KafkaListener
public class ReactiveKafkaConsumer {

  private static final FluentLogger log = FluentLogger.forEnclosingClass();

  @Topic("test")
  public void consume(ConsumerRecord<String, byte[]> record) {
    log.atInfo().log(record.value());
  }
}

However, when I switch this to a reactive consumer like so:
@KafkaListener
public class ReactiveKafkaConsumer {

  private static final FluentLogger log = FluentLogger.forEnclosingClass();

  @Topic("test")
  public void consume(Flux<ConsumerRecord<String, byte[]>> recordFlux) {
    log.atInfo().log("Just log. Don't process anything...");

It immediately fails with:

[Consumer clientId=xxx] Value Deserializers with error:
Deserializers{keyDeserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer@e966f7d,
valueDeserializer=JsonObjectSerde:
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord} ... No bean
introspection available for type [class
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord]. Ensure the class is
annotated with io.micronaut.core.annotation.Introspected

I've looked through the docs and sample code for using reactive streams is pretty limited. Has anyone managed to effectively consume Kafka messages in a reactive manner?
